# How do you play tennis with a keyboard/mouse in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, keyboard, mouse

Supposedly there are three different shots with LMB, RMB, and SPACE.  I think so anyway because after I saw the tutorial once and can't get it back, nothing appears in settings either.   I know space was supposed to do a lob shot, but didn't seem to do anything like it.   Also you're supposed to be able to aim your shots moving the mouse left and right I think.   I don't seem to be able to control any shots after the serve with anything I do though.   Whatever I hit, the ball just goes the same normal shot right down the center.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Wiki pages for the terms (top/bottom spin, lob), [GTAGuide](https://gtaguide.net/gta5/misc/tennis/), and experience winning 1:5 played so far. RMB carried hard once I found it, push Amanda to the back line and then ***boop***.

- LMB - Basic swing: No spin, average speed and distance.
- RMB - Top spin - Forward rolling motion,  falling arc, low bounce.
- L Shift - Bottom spin: Backwards rolling motion, goes low and far, high bounce.
- Space - Lob shot: Self-adjusting to go near if opponent is far and far if they're near.
- Mouse movement - Aim  serve: In between starting and hitting the mouse can be moved to make minor adjustments to the aim.

Comment: Thanks, but in regards to this: " For example, if the opponent is near the net on the left side, send the ball to the back line on the right side"  how do you control left and right after the serve?    Is it placement of the character vs. the ball and timing?  I see the tips now when playing easy mode at least after the serve so I was able to look at them and at least see the key binds, but nothing explains how to aim to the right side of the court when the opponent is on the left.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find a way to aim shots either, other than character placement as you were thinking. Purely speculation, but with the controls already so janky they may have decided it wasn't worth implementing.